# Permute only certain elements in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

Consider this array:

```
array = np.array([2, 4, 23, 11, 0, 9])
```

Is there a way to get a random permutation of the elements with odd index?

Example of possible outputs:

```
[2, 11, 23, 4, 0, 9]
[2, 4, 23, 9, 0, 11]
```

Note that the elements with even index, 2, 23, 0 should stay fixed

Comment: Your question could be re-phrased as - how do I index the *odd* elements and operate on them - [Numpy Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select all odd elements using `array[1::2]`, and shuffle them using `np.random.shuffle()`:

```
np.random.shuffle(array[1::2])
```

Comment: Note that this shuffles the *values at odd indices*, and not elements that have an odd value. I know this is correct and what OP asked for, but the statement "You can select all odd elements using `array[1::2]`" confused me a little at first. This could be a useful clarification for some readers.